# Equalize histogram for HSV image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to equalise the histogram of a HSV image using openCV and C++.
I know there are libraries with openCV that will do this for me but i want to try it manually to understand the method.

I am assuming that the equalisation will be done on the V channel of the HSV image?
I have found a method for greyscale histogram equalisation which involves

- Count Number of pixels of each value
- Find probability of each pixel in image
- Calculate the cumulative distribution function
- Calculate the CDF * Max value in image.
- Round this number to get the pixel value

I have tried this method on paper with a simple 5x5 grid of values and it seemed to give the effect of equalising the values.

I have tried to implement this in C++ but I am not getting the values i expected.

```
int rows = channel.rows;
int cols = channel.cols;
int hist[256];
int total = rows*cols;
for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k<cols; k++ )
    {
        int value = channel.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,k)[0];
        hist[value] = hist[value] + 1;
    }
}

double prob[255];
int newValues[255];
double cuml = 0;
for(int j = 0; j< 255; j++)
{
    prob[j] = hist[j]/total; // Probability of each value in image
    cuml = cuml + prob[j]; // Cumulative probability of current and all previous values
    double cdfmax = cuml * 255;   // Cumulative probability * max value
    newValues[j] = (int) round(cdfmax);
    cout << hist[j] << endl;
    cout << prob[j] << endl;
}
```

Channel is a Mat image representing the V values of my HSV image. I am pretty sure the problem lies in the first for loop to sum up all occurrences of that value in the image. I am fairly new to C++ so there may well be other errors as well.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to initialize your `hist` array to zeros for example like this:

```
int hist[256] = {0};
```

Update:

`prob[j] = hist[j]/total;` will always result in 0 since you are doing integer division (both terms are `int`-s). To avoid this do `prob[j] = hist[j]/(double)total;`.

The second part of the code is only using 255 values of your histogram (however it has 256 bins). So update it to 256, like this:

```
double prob[256];
int newValues[256];
double cuml = 0;
for(int j = 0; j< 256; j++)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that has given me more realistic values. The issue now is the probabilities are all coming out at 0. 
The total number of pixels calculated by rows*cols = 234164.
And i calculate the probability as:
Number of each pixel value/total.
I have also initialized the other arrays to 0.

Comment: Excellent! Completed the lookup table and result looks the same as the openCV library method so I guess that means its correct. Thank you.